# Can hair short an electrical circuit?

Tags: components, short-circuit, fault

Taking this as an example - if a strand of hair gets in say in cpu socket of a PC or any other slot of device, what would be the consequences, rather the symptoms if the hair gets in between those pins:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, not at this voltage. But it could 'open' the circuit and change the impedance of the circuit in the case of a CPU socket. If hair got in between one of the pins and the contacts there could be a problem.

Hair resistance is probably in the MΩ range, I couldn't measure anything with my meter and it goes up to 10 MΩ.

The pins on a processor need to make contact, hair is not going to help that situation and could open the circuit. Use 'dust off' or something to get it out.

Comment: I'm imagining someone using an LGA socket as a hairbrush

Comment: It depends what kind of hair you use. Human hair should be ok up to 2.2GHz, but if you use cat then it's fine up to 3.2GHz. Dog hair is useful for low power applications, as it limits the frequency to 1.5GHz which uses less energy.

Comment: @BeB00 Nicely done :)

Comment: @BeB00 They would use a [PGA chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_grid_array), probably an old Pentium.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google shows that most of the time hair is an insulator, so a hair getting in will make it mechanically hard to plug it and possibly cause an open circt.

First however, define your hair.... Wet/with hair gel/oil/spray/dog/cat/dyed/etc then use google (or alternative) to find the conductivity of it. (Alternatively, experiment yourself)

Comment: So would the pc boot?

Comment: Depends which socket and which pins and so on. Assuming it's blocking the pins on the CPU socket, the motherboard will boot up and think that there's no CPU. Then it depends on the motherboard, but I'd expect some fault message would come out in some way.

Comment: Apart from some fault message or beeps or trouble of 'clean boot',would there be performance issues?Lesser performance of that system...

Comment: Possibly, but I wouldn't expect it. It could be temperamental I suppose... It's a 1min job to take your CPU out if it's a concern of yours, so check it.

Comment: Hey @puffafish,dont have any additional thermal paste,if the cpu has to be removed...and minute sized hair is undetectable..:-(

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, breaking the contact is the biggest issue.

Dry hair is a good insulator, but hair is also great at absorbing moisture...

It can, under certain conditions absorb up to 45% it's weight in moisture. Add a little sweat salts and you have a conductor. As such a stray hair in a high humidity environment could introduce a current path that is detrimental to the functionality of the device.

Comment: Can that be detected by any software?without removing the components..

Comment: @SomaPaul Very unlikely.  Either the computer will work fine, or it will malfunction.